# Please add support for embedded YouTube videos

Tags: feature-request, design

YouTube support is currently enabled on [Gaming and Music](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/13531). Considering the number of questions involving a specific play from a game, or a demonstration of a technique, I think Sports should allow embedded videos also.

Some questions that would benefit:

- [Is it legal to throw an alley-oop to yourself in a real game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/324/is-it-legal-to-throw-an-alley-oop-to-yourself-off-the-backboard)
- [How do you correctly learn how to hockey stop](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/27/how-to-correctly-learn-to-hockey-stop)
- [Is taking a step before dribbling the ball a travel?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/736/is-taking-a-step-before-dribbling-the-ball-a-travel)

(I'm sure there are others; these just came from a quick search for "YouTube".)

So how about it?

Comment: I'll all for it!

Comment: [Join the club!](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/79/can-we-get-youtube-support-turned-on)

Comment: is there any progress being done on this front??

Answer (score 2):

It's been 5 years and there's still no progress on embedding YouTube videos. Is it not enabled because we are in the beta version and first we need to graduate or it doesn't matter?

Here are the [list of the SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers#answer-104189) that currently support embedding YouTube videos. *(All of them are graduated).* My suggestion is to list examples of questions/answers like [in this post from Movies SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/631/video-embedding-for-movies-se/1311#1311) where embedding a YouTube video would improve the quality of the question/answer.

### The List:

- [Who is awarded the assist when a receiving player deliberately leaves the ball for another player, who scores?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/15891/12991) (In this answer I'm using very demonstrative counter example via YouTube video)
- [Shot on target with deflection - a goal or an own goal](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15729/shot-on-target-with-deflection-a-goal-or-an-own-goal) *(This and the next question are asked referencing the specific game play)*
- [Is an own goal scored with hand a valid goal?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15861/is-an-own-goal-scored-with-hand-a-valid-goal)
- *...Include your questions/answers...*

It's also worth to mention some notes from [this answer by Robert Cartaino](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1311/50096):

> Video is not searchable. I'd hate to see a potentially well-worded
> question that describes the problem reduced to a video link asking
> "What does this scene mean?" That will contribute absolutely
> nothing to the future of this site. It's a black box to the rest of
> the Internet.

We shall always try to avoid this type of useless content.

Comment: I posted this answer and made it community wiki, because "suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag wiki posts on meta" and hence OP was non-editable.

Comment: To clarify the previous @gdrt94's comment, the posts on meta are not editable by users not having [editing privileges](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (which is obtained at 1k on beta sites and 2k on graduated sites). Making the post [community wiki](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) lowers this threshold.